# Please suggest a combinatoric book which is written in story-like format

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation

Story-like format as in we get a feeling to be on a journey with author from one topic to another.A book in which it appears that the author is having a conversation with the reader. Searching some combinatoric topic I found pdf of a book like this but due to exam time I stuck with the standard book in my university (Discrete mathematics and its applications by Kenneth H. Rosen).Later I could not find that book(don't remember book name or author).

It would be very helpful if you can suggest any such books on combinatorics.
It would be great if someone can (somehow) name the book I found by the very vague details(mentioned below) I remember about the book.

This is a very hazy recollection so please bear with me.Read some combinatorics part of the book in which the author gives his own *Title*(different from what it is generally called) to a particular topics.At the end of the topic there is a line similar to - 
"Let us suppose you are at a party discussing mathematics and a problem related to this topic comes up.If you say that this problem can be solved by this Title everyone else will be confused because this topic/*Title* in general is known by so and so name".
I don't remember that if it was general book on discrete mathematics or a book on combinatorics.But I think it was a book solely on combinatorics.

Comment: I hope you get an answer before this question is closed as "not about mathematics".

Comment: correct place to ask this question would be?

Comment: I don't know of a better place to ask. Sorry.

Comment: Correct place: any Harry Potter forum. With information that vague, only divination can help to get the answer.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Wow, you must be fun at parties. The OP seems to be quite honest and clear about the information at hand. You would be surprised about the passages people remember from books. :)

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff♦ With all due respect, but how would that be related to the purpose of Stack Exchange *Mathematics*? Especially since what the OP remembers is not connected with mathematics in any way.